# (TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'full_name')

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, replit

```
def add_application_to_db(job_id, data):
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = text("INSERT INTO applications (full_name, email, education, work_experience, resume_url) VALUES ( :full_name, :email, :resume_url, :education, :work_experience)")
    conn.execute(query,
                 full_name = data['full_name'],
                 email = data['email'],
                 education = data['education'],
                 work_experience = data['work_experience'],
                 resume_url = data['resume_url']
                )
```

i want to try the data is go on my database i will show yoy the table that i made

this is my sql table thta i made to store my data from website to DB.

```
CREATE TABLE applications(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
job_id INT NOT NULL,
full_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
linkedin_url VARCHAR(500),
education VARCHAR(2000),
work_experience VARCHAR(5000),
resume_url VARCHAR(500),
PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
```

Comment: Please post your error message as well as the code of the sql engine you have created. You can manipulate user name and password and provided the connection string in the question. Also include the HTML snippet on how you have defined the method to accept the values as an input

Comment: `full_name`  is not a valid keyword argument for `conn.execute()`....

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)